# How does Value Reassignment works in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I wonder how does exactly Value Reassignment works behind the scene in JavaScript.

as I know variable points to address, let's say **age** variable points to #0001 which holds value 50:

> age => address: #**0001**   value: **50**;

then after reassignment it will be like that:

> age => address: #**0002**   value: **55**;

Now I wonder: does after reassignment both **let age** and **age** points to the last address (address: #**0002**   value: **55**)? or a new **age** variable is separately/different variable from the beginning variable(**let age**)?

if my question is obscure then please explain me how does Value Reassignment works. Thanks in advance

```js
let age = 50
console.log(age); //Logs: 50
age = 55
console.log(age); //logs: 55
```

Comment: The address of the variable doesn't change when it's reassigned.

Comment: As Barmar states, variables work simply like this: you have a bucket with a name on it and you can put different pieces of data in it. A reassignment uses the same bucket (name and location), and you replaced the old item that was in the bucket with something else. That's it. The only complexity is whether the item in the bucket is a reference/non-primitive object or if it's just a literal immutable value like `50` and `55` are.

Comment: Whilst I only have a vague understanding of the inner workings, I am somehow convinced that this can be the subject of implementation specific choices. Javascript engines do have to follow specific set of rules but afair details are not really specified. I can easily be wrong and I find it interesting to learn :)

Comment: What happens internally is entirely up to the engine. You should primarily worry about what the spec tells you about how the engine has to behave towards the outside.

Comment: You cannot get the address of a variable in JavaScript. As far as you (the programmer) are concerned, they don't have addresses. This is an implementation detail that is not exposed to you in any way.

Comment: When in doubt with a question like this, just test it. Open up the devtools and write up a few lines of code to see what happens. Then you know how it works.

Comment: @ggorlen you are both wrong, I prove it with this example: age = 20; oldAge = age; age = 25; console.log(oldAge) //logs: 20  console.log(age) //logs:25 | so based on this example if age's address didn't changed, then oldAge would be 25 as well. But as you see oldAge is 20, therefore after rassignment age"s address is changed. And oldAge points to old address which holds value 20;

Comment: @Leonardo Re-check this: _The only complexity is whether the item in the bucket is a reference/non-primitive object or if it's just a literal immutable value like 50 and 55 are._ In your "counter example", the variable `oldAge` is a separate bucket, and you copied a primitive number value into it. After `oldAge = age` you have two buckets with two different pieces of data in them, so changing one won't affect the other. `oldAge` is not an alias of `age`--this would only be true if the value was a non-primitive object.

Answer (score 2):

Declaring a variable associates the name with a memory location.

Assigning the variable simply fills in the contents at the associated location, it doesn't create a new variable.

A declaration with an initial value is roughly equivalent to the declaration followed by an assignment.

This is all conceptual, the actual mechanics behind the scenes are implementation-dependent.

Comment: `Assigning the variable simply fills in the contents at the associated location` is this really always true? If a value of a different type is assigned to that variable and the new type needs more space then the previously assigned variable then the memory location might change.

Comment: The location of the value changes, the location of the variable doesn't.

Comment: The value of a variable is a reference to the value. That's how two variables can contain the same object.

Comment: @Barmar it's wrong, I prove it with this example: age = 20; oldAge = age; age = 25; console.log(oldAge) //logs: 20 console.log(age) //logs:25 | so based on this example if age's address didn't changed, then oldAge would be 25 as well. But as you see oldAge is 20, therefore after rassignment age"s address is changed. And oldAge points to old address which holds value 20;

Comment: The assignment copies the value, it doesn't make the two variables equivalent.

Comment: `age` is at location 1, `oldAge` is at location 2. `oldAge = age` means to copy what's in location 1 to location 2. `age = 25` then replaces what's in location 1, this has no effect on location 2.

Comment: Hi @Barmar
"Assigning the variable simply fills in the contents at the associated location"
Is this true for primitive data types? I've read in many places that since primitives are immutable, every time a reassignment happens, a new bucket is made for the variable and it now points towards that bucket. The reference to the previous value is lost and is later garbage collected.

Comment: Those are implementation details. As I said, I was describing it at the conceptual level.